# C++ circular includes with internal structs

Tags: c++, struct, circular-dependency

I have a question about circulars includes that made me crazy:

#### main.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"

int main()
{
    A a();
    B b();
    return 0;
}
```

#### A.hpp

```
#ifndef _CLASS_A
#define _CLASS_A

#include "B.hpp"
class A
{
    public: 
        B* b;
        struct A_t
        {
            int id;
        };
};
#endif
```

#### B.hpp

```
#ifndef _CLASS_B
#define _CLASS_B

#include "A.hpp"

class B
{
    class A;  //Ok, with that I can use the class A
    public: 
        int a;
        A* b;  // That work!
        A::A_t *aStruct; // Opss! that throw a compilation error.

};
#endif
```

The question is: ¿How can I use the A_t struct in the class B?

I have tryed to add a forward declaration like:

```
struct  A::A_t;
```

But that obviously does work.

Comment: Just to note, when we say `throw` in relation to an error it usually means at runtime, i.e an exception. If you have a compiler error message, let us know what it is.

Comment: A a; or A *a= new A();
It is not important for this example, just here to show that I need to create an object.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the include in `A.h` with a forward declaration.

```
#ifndef _CLASS_A
#define _CLASS_A
class B;
class A
{
    public: 
        B* b;
        struct A_t
        {
            int id;
        };
};
#endif
```

Also, note that

```
A a();
B b();
```

won't create two instances of the classes, but they're function declarations. You want

```
A a;
B b;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your fast response, but I cannot do that:

That example is, of course, a simplification of the real code: I cannot change anything of the class A, so all changes, should be made in the B.hpp file.

Sorry if the description of the problem was a bit confusing.